# Not getting values from linq query in aspnetzero framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetzero

I am executing following query. I am doing this in aspnetzero framework and doing this in UserAppService.cs file.

```
var rt = _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().Users
                    .Where(e => e.Id == 11)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But this is always returning null, in database there is record with Id = 11.

So anyone has any idea what is wrong in this.

Thanks

Comment: Chances are your application is using a connection string to a database you aren't expecting. Check the value of `_dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().Database.Connection.ConnectionString` to verify that it is connecting to the same database server/instance you are inspecting for records. Also check that your context hasn't added alternate tables based on the naming convention. (I.e. under default namespace or pluralized class name)

Comment: Try to add `.IgnoreQueryFilters()`, probably you have defined query filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Svyatoslav Danyliv said in the comment, the issue is related to the query filters, try to add the `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` to ignore the query filters.